# What is chain decimal?

Tags: polkadot, parachain

I saw token decimal has different value like 12, 10, 6 in different substrate chain, What exactly it means and what is the use of it?

Answer (score 3):

This is the number of decimals on your main token. Compare with fiat currencies a euro has a decimal value of `2` and a cup of coffee is 0.99 Euro, while in Japan a Japanese yen (for all practical use) has a decimal value of `0` and a cup of coffee is 120 yen.

On a chain all currencies are a huge integer number, but since that is confusing for humans, these integers are treated as a fix point decimal number system instead.

Calling the RPC `system.properties` will reveal this information for any chain. For instance polkadot as 10

```
system.properties: ChainProperties
{
  isEthereum: false
  ss58Format: 0
  tokenDecimals: [
    10
  ]
  tokenSymbol: [
    DOT
  ]
}
```

So `1 DOT` is represented internally by `10^10`

When encoding operations on the chain values are given in the internal u128 integer format, any tool communication with the chain should do this conversion for the user.

Comment: on what basics should we define fix point decimal number for chain? Is it random value or it has some meaning? @Simon

Comment: @Ganesh11 - there's an unfortunate terminology problem here where it pays to be precise.  The _fixed point_ number can mean two things.  First, when doing any kind of arithmetic, remember it is a _binary_ number - therefore you have the typical problems of representing fractions that you think of as _decimal_ fractions in binary - that is, all the problems that surface with multiples of `0.1`.  So when you _do_ use the bits to the right of the implied "binary point" separating whole from fractional: be careful.  The other use is that all numbers representing amounts of your token are ...

Comment: ... represented as a whole number of the _smallest_ unit of that token.  In the example in this answer, the precision is _ten decimal digits_ to the right of the decimal point, so an amount of 1 token is actually represented as `10_000_000_000`.  On a chain such as Ethereum, using Uniswap contracts for examples, fractions there - used for computing liquidity equations for example -  are represented as a `128.128` fixed point binary number - which would mean you take your 1 token = `10_000_000_000` "units" (whatever you call them) and multiply _that_ by `2¹²⁸`.

Comment: If you're asking how you define your fixed point (i.e., number of decimal digits) for your token - that depends on your use case moderated by the fact that the entire expected treasury amount must fit on the _left_ side of the implied point, and the smallest units you expect to use _plus some more digits for arithmetic precision when multiplying by a fraction, or dividing_ need to fit on the _right_ side.  Look around for existing examples, and make an educated guess as to what you need.